# Auto Replace feature in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a column in google sheets that shows whether someone paid cash or card. I currently have functions in place to make the colors change based on if "cash" or "card" are typed, but I want to make this faster to fill. Both words start with "c" so I can't really shorten the words that way. I want to make it so if I type "1" it will automatically be replaced with "cash" in this column and "2" will be replaced by "card". But all the REPLACE function I can find have are replacing pre-existing information with new information, not creating a function for future info. Is this something I can do on google sheets? if so does anyone know how to set this up/the function for it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way ... you could take advantage of custom number formatting.

1. select the whole column
2. Format`>`Number`>`Custom Number Format
3. write this: `[= 1] "Cash"; [= 2] "Card"; "no choice"`

From this moment on by writing 1 you will see "Cash" instead, by writing 2 you will see "Card" ... any other number will be changed to "no choice" ... any text will remain unchanged.

***note that in the cells there are really numbers and NOT writings, which however will be what you will see***

[image: custom]